# How to change timezone with Offset when Deserializing DateTime using JSON.NET in Azure APIM?

Tags: datetime, json.net, deserialization, azure-api-management, apim

I'm using Azure APIM policy expression to aggregate multiple responses. In that one of the JSON response contains multiple dateTime fields. all of them are in UTC TZ. I want to deserialize all of the date fields to specific Timezone(in my case SGT +08:00) from +00:00

Input:

```json
{
    "Header": {
        "UserID": "xxxxxx",
        "MessageID": "xxxxxx",
        "CorrelationID": "xxxx",
        "DateTime": "2018-02-12T15:31:18+00:00",
        "ReqID": "xxx"
    },
    "ResultSet": {
        "Tier": {
            "CardSuffix": "91",
            "RetentionDeadline": "2022-02-27T16:00:00+00:00",
            "PointsRequireToQualify": "xxxxx",
            "QualifyingDeadline": "2022-02-27T16:00:00+00:00",
            "SignupDate": "2020-08-07",
            "IssuedDate": "2021-06-15",
            "JoiningDateTime": "2010-03-31T10:10:00+00:00",
            "RequireToUpgradeInYear": "288886",
            "YearlyUpgradeDeadline": "2022-02-27T16:00:00+00:00",
            "CurrentCardDesc": "xxxxxxxx",
            "NextCardDesc": "xxxxxxxxx",
            "CurrentTierPoints": "0",
            "UpdatedDateTime": "2023-01-09T17:43:54.844+00:00",
            "LastRefreshedDateTime": "2022-02-10T07:45:13+00:00"
        }
    }
}
```

Expected Output:

```json
{
    "Header": {
        "UserID": "xxxxxx",
        "MessageID": "xxxxxx",
        "CorrelationID": "xxxx",
        "DateTime": "2018-02-12T15:31:18+08:00",
        "ReqID": "xxx"
    },
    "ResultSet": {
        "Tier": {
            "CardSuffix": "91",
            "RetentionDeadline": "2022-02-28T0:00:00+08:00",
            "PointsRequireToQualify": "xxxxx",
            "QualifyingDeadline": "2022-02-28T0:00:00+08:00",
            "SignupDate": "2020-08-07",
            "IssuedDate": "2021-06-15",
            "JoiningDateTime": "2010-03-31T10:10:00+08:00",
            "RequireToUpgradeInYear": "288886",
            "YearlyUpgradeDeadline": "2022-02-28T0:00:00+08:00",
            "CurrentCardDesc": "xxxxxxxx",
            "NextCardDesc": "xxxxxxxxx",
            "CurrentTierPoints": "0",
            "UpdatedDateTime": "2023-01-10T22:08:08+08:00",
            "LastRefreshedDateTime": "2022-02-10T15:45:13+08:00"
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried and achieved the expected output by using [ConvertTimeBySystemTimeZoneId(DateTimeOffset, String)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timezoneinfo.converttimebysystemtimezoneid?view=net-7.0#system-timezoneinfo-converttimebysystemtimezoneid(system-datetimeoffset-system-string)) Method, But real Problem is I don't want to add each individual Property name  to change the time zone with Offset. I need generic efficient solution that deserialize DateTime fields to Specific TimeZone with the format `.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTH:mm::sszzz")`

Here's my fiddle: [sample](https://dotnetfiddle.net/AhBRsb)

If you see my above sample, I have parse the input as JObject and converts to required format for the first property alone
`obj["ResultSet"]["Tier"]["RetentionDeadline"]` which changed from `"RetentionDeadline": "2022-02-27T16:00:00+00:00",` to `"RetentionDeadline": "2022-02-28T0:00:00+08:00",`

**Problem with this solution:**
If any new DateField is added in the backend response, I need to revisit my policy expression again and do this manual conversion. So I want generic one time conversion for all dateTime fields.

Please note that I'm writing this inside [policy expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-policy-expressions); so I can't reuse the functionality by using any c# extensions or helper methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by looping over the children of the JSON object:

```cs
var obj = context.Request.Body.AsJObject(true, new JsonSerializerSettings() { DateParseHandling = DateParseHandling.None } );
foreach (JProperty x in (JToken)obj["ResultSet"]["Tier"])
{}
```

[DateParseHandling](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_DateParseHandling.htm) is used for the date format does not change.

A very simple Regex is used to recognize dates `2022-02-27T`:

`^[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}T`

Complete policy:

```xml
<policies>
    <inbound>
        <base />
        <return-response>
            <set-status code="200" reason="OK" />
            <set-header name="Content-Type" exists-action="override">
                <value>application/json</value>
            </set-header>
            <set-body>@{   
                var obj = context.Request.Body.AsJObject(true, new JsonSerializerSettings() { DateParseHandling = DateParseHandling.None } );

                var pattern = @"^[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}T";
                var regex = new Regex(pattern);

                foreach (JProperty x in (JToken)obj["ResultSet"]["Tier"])
                { 
                    string name = x.Name;
                    JToken tokenValue = x.Value;

                    if(regex.IsMatch(tokenValue.ToString()))
                    {
                        obj["ResultSet"]["Tier"][name] = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeBySystemTimeZoneId(new DateTimeOffset(Convert.ToDateTime(obj["ResultSet"]["Tier"][name])), "Singapore Standard Time").ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTH:mm::sszzz");
                    }
                }

                return obj.ToString();
            }</set-body>
        </return-response>
    </inbound>
    <backend>
        <base />
    </backend>
    <outbound>
        <base />
    </outbound>
    <on-error>
        <base />
    </on-error>
</policies>
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, Marcus! I simply added a few empty string checks in addition to the RegEx approach for DateTime conversion. It was successful.

Answer (score 0):

Update: My backend has been sending proper TimeZone data.

If your response has a Proper DateTime field with TimeZone and you want to keep the original value in TimeZone, this `DateParseHandling = DateParseHandling.None` can be used.

Below is an example Snippet.

https://dotnetfiddle.net/AlPJmk

This could be useful to someone.